# Extract rows of data frames on a list based on other data frame

Tags: r, list, extract

If I want to extract rows from a single data frame based on another one I use this:

```
data<- dat[dat$ABC %in% cod$ABC, ]
```

Now I have a list of data frames and a data frame. How can I extract rows from every data frame on the list based on the other data frame?

Comment: Please make your question more reproducible by following suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If `cod` is the second dataframe, `lapply(list1, function(x) x[x$ABC %in% cod$ABC,])`